# How can we make an animated strike through on react native text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have a todo list, each list item has a check box. When I check the box, an animated strike-through effect should show from left to right. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't animate strike directly but I used some tricks to achieve the same effect.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef(View.prototype);
  const animatedValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const [textWidth, setTextWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const [textHeight, setTextHeight] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.measure((x, y, w, h) => {
      setTextWidth(w);
      setTextHeight(h);
      animateStrike();
    });
  }, []);

  const animateStrike = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const strikeWidth = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, textWidth],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text} ref={ref}>
          Some Dummy Text
        </Text>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.strike,
            { width: strikeWidth, top: textHeight / 2 + 1 },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  strike: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

You can check the demo [here](https://snack.expo.io/l9n-DBTtC).

Comment: I dont know why this code is not working in my local machine

Comment: @SupriyaGorai Did you check snack?

Comment: @SupriyaGorai I'm glad. Thanks. Good luck.

Comment: @J.Dow how can I reset the animation again? like I have a checkbox when clicking on the check box the animation is done correctly. but when I am unchecking the checkbox and check again the animation is not showing, it is showing like a normal strike through

Comment: @J.Done  check this - https://snack.expo.io/@supu/414e51

Comment: @SupriyaGorai How can you handle unchecking?

Comment: Inside **handleCheckBox** function before everything write following `if (!isChecked) animatedValue.setValue(0);`.

Comment: I updated your [snack](https://snack.expo.io/bon-JmV89).

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please suggest any course or youtube to learn react-native animation ?

Comment: @SupriyaGorai [This](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-animations-using-the-animated-api-ebe8e0669fae) helped me when I was a beginner. If you prefer to react-native-reanimated then [this](https://codedaily.io/courses/7/React-Native-Reanimated-Fundamentals) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve `strikethough` text with animation but you can customize it with the way like it's doing here [Text animation with CSS - strike through line](https://dev.to/shrek7/text-animation-with-css-strike-through-line-ea6)

You can create custom horizontal `ProgressBar` and animate it with absolute on `Text` so It might look the same you want.